# images are not properly shown in webpage

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, device

I am completely new to bootstrap. And I have made an website in Bootstrap 3.0.
the website was working properly on my laptop. But when I hosted that website some of the images are not loaded in webpage. And further when i try to open the website in mobile device the carousel images are not fitted to carousel i mean it leaves some blank space it does not cover the entire carousel space. And while loading the website on the mobile device the background image is also not fully fitted to screen. Please help me out I am totally stuck. my website url is [WWW.krishzone.com](http://krishzone.com)

and my code is

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Krishh Kidss Zone</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body style="background: url(../img/background1.png) no-repeat center center fixed"
style="-webkit-background-size: cover"
style="moz-background-size: cover"
style="-o-background-size: cover"
style="background-size: cover">
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Krishh Kidss Zone</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="whykrishkids.html">Why Krishh Kidss</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="admission.html">Admissions</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="achivements.html">Achivements</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Header Carousel -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
            <img src="../img/school.jpg" alt="learn" style="max-width:100%" style="height:auto" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Krishh Kidss Zone...</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="../img/learning.JPG" alt="Fun" style="max-width:100%" style="height:auto" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Where Learning is...</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="../img/playing.jpg" alt="play" style="max-width:100%" style="height:auto" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Fun</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">
                Krishh Kidss Zone
            </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Vision</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                    "To make your child grow into complete personality and develop the strength to meet the challenges ahed."
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    </p>
                    <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="vision.html" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>About Us</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>We have started Krishh Kidss Zone pre school in 11th February 2010 with motto to give best primary education to children with out any burden. We adopt the simple and effective slogan “Where learning is Fun” , where we always focus on the children’s learning with the help of fun.</p>
                    <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Events</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                    We celebrate almost each and every festivals and days as a part of our curriculam. That will help the children to know and understand the impotance of the festivals and days. We try to fill the colours in education by celebrating such events.
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    </p>                        
                    <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="events.html" class="btn btn-default">See More</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Features Section -->



    <!-- /.row -->

    <hr>

    <!-- Call to Action Section -->
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3> Contact Us:</h3>

                <p>Adress:<br/>
                18 Sarita Vihar,<br/>
                Opp. Kartavya Bunglows,<br/>
                Anand Nadiad Road,<br/>
                Lambhvel, 387-310<br/>
                Anand, Gujarat</p><br/>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Contact Details<br/>
            Ph.No. +91 99799 64200             <br/>
            Like Us On Facebook
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline list-social-icons">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Krishkidszone?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul></p>
            <p>Copyright &copy; Krishh Kidss Zone 2015</p>
            <p>Developed By: Shree InfoTech Ltd.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: @spinon Do I need to edit path for the image ??

Comment: You could to make the example work better. I was just updating the formatting of the HTML because it was breaking up in the middle.

Comment: @spinon ohk. Got it . I have solved the issue regarding the images but the carousel and background image still remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `div` and `nav` tags that are duplicates or out of place completely. Your images inside the carousel contain multiple `style` tags `style="max-width:100%" style="height:auto"` which should be `style="max-width:100%; height:auto;"` but are unnecessary and should go into a stylesheet if you do need to apply rules.

This example should provide a better starting point for you.

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
```

```css
body {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1350x1050/5E58D1/fff/) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #3A368C;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #FAF2F2;
  background-color: #161263;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #FAF2F2;
  background-color: #3C3880;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #5E58D1;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel.fade .item {
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  left: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel.fade .item:first-child {
  top: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel.fade .item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav id="#custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Krishh Kidss Zone</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us </a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="whykrishkids.html">Why Krishh Kidss</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="admission.html">Admissions</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Events</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="achivements.html">Achivements</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel fade">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://desktop-pictorials.com/SingleScreen/SinglePage01/Island002-1920x1080.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://img.phombo.com/img1/photocombo/4448/The_Best_HD_HQ_Hi-Res_Wallpapers_Collection_-_Cityscape_by_tonyx__145_pictures-61.jpg_HDTV_monaco_1920x1080.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('https://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/7yz4ma1/01407_harboursunset_1920x1080.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
  </a>
</header>
<div class="container">

  <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="page-header"> Krishh Kidss Zone </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Vision</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>"To make your child grow into complete personality and develop the strength to meet the challenges ahed."
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
          </p>
          <div class="text-center"> <a href="vision.html" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>About Us</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>We have started Krishh Kidss Zone pre school in 11th February 2010 with motto to give best primary education to children with out any burden. We adopt the simple and effective slogan “Where learning is Fun” , where we always focus on the children’s
            learning with the help of fun.</p>
          <div class="text-center"> <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Events</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>We celebrate almost each and every festivals and days as a part of our curriculam. That will help the children to know and understand the impotance of the festivals and days. We try to fill the colours in education by celebrating such events.
            <br/>
            <br/>
          </p>
          <div class="text-center"> <a href="events.html" class="btn btn-default">See More</a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Features Section -->

  <!-- /.row -->

  <hr>

  <!-- Call to Action Section -->
  <div class="well">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3> Contact Us:</h3>
        <p>Adress:
          <br/>18 Sarita Vihar,
          <br/>Opp. Kartavya Bunglows,
          <br/>Anand Nadiad Road,
          <br/>Lambhvel, 387-310
          <br/>Anand, Gujarat</p>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Contact Details
          <br/>Ph.No. +91 99799 64200
          <br/>Like Us On Facebook
          <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline list-social-icons">
            <li> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Krishkidszone?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </p>
        <p>Copyright &copy; Krishh Kidss Zone 2015</p>
        <p>Developed By: Shree InfoTech Ltd.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <!-- Footer -->

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: I have solved the issue of the images but I am still not able to figure out the background problem

Comment: Have you updated the code you posted to reflect all of this?

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect the changes. But still the background image issue is not solved. Please help me out